# ORA-00907 Missing right parenthesis even when parenthesis are balanced

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error

I have a relatively straightforward sql query which refuses to execute on sqldeveloper, I've narrowed down the offending line to this -

```
and (b.date_updated > (sysdate MINUS 2) or a.date_updated > (sysdate MINUS 2))
```

This is a part of my `where` clause along with other statements.

I've visually counted the parenthesis multiple times and it looks balanced to me, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, can someone help me figure out what's wrong here.

For completeness, here's what the where clause looks like

```
where a.customer_id = b.customer_id
and (b.date_updated > (sysdate MINUS 2) or a.date_updated > (sysdate MINUS 2))
and a.c_id = c.c_id
```

Comment: `MINUS` should be `-`

Comment: How have you narrowed it down to this line?  Does the error go away if you comment out that line?

Comment: Yeah, without this line the query executes fine but I need to pick a timeframe.

Comment: Thanks guys, that fixed it. There was another error earlier which caused me to change the `-` to `MINUS`. It works as expected now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MINUS` is a set operator that operates on two sets, essentially the "opposite" of what `UNION` or `UNION ALL` does.

To subtract a number from a date (or another number) use `-`

This is documented in the chapter "Arithmetic operators" in the Oracle manual:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/operators002.htm#SQLRF51156

You confused that with a SET operator: 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/operators005.htm#SQLRF51164

To learn *why* `current_date - 2` actually does what you expect it to, please read the chapter, "*Datetime/Interval Arithmetic*":
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#i48042

Answer (score 2):

`MINUS` is not legal syntax.  Replace each `MINUS` with the actual operator `-`.

Comment: I found this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96518/cqspcl.htm which is why I changed my query to use MINUS, is there a guideline about when to use what?

Comment: `MINUS` _is_ a valid operator - just not for subtracting a number.

Comment: @nikhil: the manual you are linking to documents the full text search of a long obsolete Oracle version (note the "*Oracle Text Reference*" at the top). It is **not** about subtracting a number from a value.

Answer (score 2):

change `and (b.date_updated > (sysdate MINUS 2) or a.date_updated > (sysdate MINUS 2))` **to** `and (b.date_updated > (sysdate - 2) or a.date_updated > (sysdate - 2))`